# How can I do ToJSON for Maybe?

Tags: haskell

How can I do ToJSON for Maybe?

```
data MyData = MyData {
  id :: Int,
  something :: Maybe String
}

instance ToJSON MyData where
  toJSON (MyData id something) =
    object ["id" .= id
      , "something" .= ???
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the `ToJSON` instance of `Maybe a`.

```
data MyData = MyData {
  id        :: Int,
  something :: Maybe String
}

instance ToJSON MyData where
  toJSON (MyData id something) =
    object ["id" .= id
      , "something" .= toJSON something
    ]
```

And as [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) suggests, you can let the compiler derive an instance for you. The derived instance is exactly the same as the one above.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.TH

data MyData = MyData {
  id        :: Int,
  something :: Maybe String
} deriving (Generic, Show)

instance ToJSON MyData where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions
```